# error while insatlling gstreamer

Tags: debian

```
aptitude install gstreamer1.0-libav

Couldn't find any package whose name or description matched "gstreamer1.0-libav"
Couldn't find any package whose name or description matched "gstreamer1.0-libav"
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 97 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
```

what should i do now???:(

Answer (score 1):

I see that package in Debian testing, unstable, experimental and wheezy-backports. So I guess you are using Debian stable, alias "Wheezy".
(check the output of `apt-cache policy` to be sure, or post it here.)

If that is the case, you should simply add Wheezy-backports to your sources: add a line

```
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-backports main non-free contrib
```

in either `/etc/apt/sources.list` or better create a new file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/wheezy-backports.list` with only that line. Afterwards run `apt-get update` and you should be ready to go...

Comment: Creating a new file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/wheezy-backports.list` is unnecessary, imo. Why is that better?

Comment: Well, if not better, at least easier to manage. But of course you are free to choose ;-) The idea of all the `/etc/.../*.d` folders is that they allow different packages to install their own configuration files without colliding with changes from other packages.